# Plotting many unconnected lines in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I need to plot a lot of unconnected lines in MATLAB. This code will do it using a for loop:

```
x = 1:5;
y = 10:-2:2;
figure;
hold on;
for ii = 1:5
    plot([0,x(ii)],[0,y(ii)],'b-');
end
```

Is it possible to do the same thing without using a for loop?

Use case: I am trying to visualize a tree and there are many lines to be drawn. I would like to precalculate the end points of all the lines and call `plot` or equivalent once. This is what I am doing with `scatter` to show the nodes of the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
plot([zeros(1,length(x));x],[zeros(1,length(x));y],'r-')
```

Comment: Very elegant solution with built-in functionality

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`NaN`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) to disconnect lines when plotting. Therefore, you can concatenate your `x` and `y` values with an `NaN`-vector of the same length and then [`reshape`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) it in order to have an `NaN` to disconnect the lines in between the individual segments.

To make the code universally applicable, we introduce `xo` and `yo` to be the coordinates of the origin. Now, the points to be plotted can be calculated as follows:

```
xp = reshape([ones(size(x))*xo;x;NaN(size(x))],1,[]);
yp = reshape([ones(size(y))*yo;y;NaN(size(y))],1,[]);
```

The `xp`-vector looks like this now:

```
0   1   NaN    0   2   NaN    0   3   NaN    0   4   NaN    0   5   NaN
└ origin           └ end point of segment 2           └ to disconnect lines
```

---

The whole code to produce the same result as in your question is the following:

```
x = 1:5;
y = 10:-2:2;

figure;
xo = 0;     % x-coordinate of origin
yo = 0;     % y-coordinate of origin
xp = reshape([ones(size(x))*xo;x;NaN(size(x))],1,[]);
yp = reshape([ones(size(y))*yo;y;NaN(size(y))],1,[]);
plot(xp,yp,'b-');
```